# Create one CSS animation from 3 separate

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, bezier

I am beginner to animation in CSS and I have exported from desing file CSS animation code for animation like this.

```
@keyframes first {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes second {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes third{
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```
animation: ${first} 307ms ease-in-out 0ms normal,${second} 2193ms linear 307ms normal,
           ${third} 503ms ease-in-out 2500ms normal;
```

However I wonder if it is possible to make it in one animation? If I want to have the same times like in generated version. If so, in what way?

Comment: Instead of `from`/`to` pairs in multiple keyframe at-rules, define percentage steps in a single at-rule. E.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#when_a_keyframe_is_defined_multiple_times

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, I've done it in this way finally